# How to disable a particular plugin in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to disable vim plugin in Intellij. In jetbrains.com it says open a setting dialog via Ctrl+Alt+S, but no dialog display after I press this three keys.

Comment: Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `plugins`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Find the one you don't need -> untick -> Apply -> Restart

[image: How to open settings]
[image: Disable plugin]

Comment: It works, though it is less convenient then keyboard shortcuts.